# Trying to Install Docker Compose on Synology but can't?

Tags: linux, docker

Terminal Pic:

[image: Picture]

Hi guys, I've been scratching my head for this one. I followed many guides out there to the letter. (I'm not an experienced server/tech guy, I just follow steps, so pardon my ignorance).

At the end of following all the steps, docker-compose --version still yields `line 1: Not: command not found`.

Pretty confused what to do to get `docker-compose up`. Supposedly, docker-compose comes installed on Synology when installing docker through the package manager, but I can't even get pass this step. Any ideas?

Comment: Please don’t post text as images. If you put it as text, you can also easily censor/replace values without obscuring potentially important information. // Also, _which_ guides, specifically, did you follow?

Answer (score 0):

Because you downloaded it in the local folder try typing :

```sh
./docker-compose --version
```

when not specifying `./` the executable should be inside a directory included in the `$PATH` environment variable (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/bin`, ... )

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running docker-compose after installing Docker from the package center before tinkering with this? I remember having to do some of these manual steps in the past but it looks like docker-compose is installed with Docker these days.  I did spin up a virtual dsm 6.2 and 7 before writing this and installed docker through the package center and docker-compose was installed.

Out of the box it comes like this:
virtual DSM 6.2 has Docker 20.10.3 and compose 1.28.5
virtual DSM 7 has docker 20.10.3 and compose 1.28.5

You might try removing docker from the package center and installing it again.
In my example /var/packages/Docker/target/usr/bin has all the files including docker-compose. also maybe check if your manual downloaded docker-compose was removed from the location after the uninstall.

Hope this helps.